# how to install and apply DNN-7 skin?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

It is my first time working on DNN.

I have installed the dnn 7 and purchased fitted skin to it.

it came with two different zip files.
I installed them both but the page layout look bad, some styles work and the others stayed from the default DNN skin.

first I need to know if I will succeed to install the skin right, after the installation is the page suppose to look exactly like the demo?

or I will need to do some work around to achieve the demo layout and style?

what I mean is that I dont know if the skin package including the slider images etc.. and all it need to be looked like the demo.

in case I did something wrong in the skin installation process it will be great 
if someone have tutorial link for DNN-7 for how to apply skin from A-Z and achieve the demo result it can help me too.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some instructions for installing a skin in DNN 7](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/544/View/Details/How-to-install-a-Skin-in-DotNetNuke-7.aspx)

[Here is an older video about how to apply skins at the Site Settings level](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/160/View/Details/Applying-Skins-and-Containers-in-Site-Settings.aspx)

You might also want to watch [DotNetNuke Explained: Basic Skinning](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/435/View/Details/DotNetNuke-Explained-Basic-Skinning.aspx)

As for your skin, and how it looks on your site. You might check with the developer of the skin to see if it is for DNN7 or not, some skins don't work well in DNN7.

All skins need more work after installing though, you still have to go through and apply the skins to pages, and move modules around into the appropriate locations (panes) based on the skin and content.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply installed through add extension process, like modules.